# Video not loading in EJS, (node.js server)

Tags: html, node.js, express, ejs

**I am using node.js server to upload a video. I am successfully able to add it in /public/uploads folder of my project and save the FilePath to MongoDB.**

Inside my **ejs, file**, I am retrieving videos, by following segment of code

```
//Videos is the array of objects which I have retrieved from mongoDB
//video.VideoFilePath is in the form "public/uploads/1591780899727_Test_00000.mp4" (i.e filename.mp4)
<%Videos.forEach(function(video){%>
        <video width="320" height="240" controls>
            <source src="<%=video.VideoFilePath%>" type="video/mp4">
        </video> 
<%});%>
```

**In the console, I a getting the following errors**

```
HTTP “Content-Type” of “text/html” is not supported. Load of media resource http://localhost:5000/public/uploads/1591780899727_Test_00000.mp4 failed.
All candidate resources failed to load. Media load paused.
```

**Earlier I thought this might be due to path, but I have tried using the absolute path as well it doesn't work.** I have tested on both Firefox and chrome, it doesn't work in any case.

I have taken care of public directory inside my app.js, if that is the concern.

**app.js**

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
```

Kindly, lemme know how can I fix this I have read many stack overflow posts, none seems to help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I realized I hadn't set my Video File Path Source as a static directory

In my app.js I added this

```js
app.use('/videofiles', express.static('/videofiles'))
```

hope this helps.